# creating rails method for checking object if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods

I am using Devise for authentication in my rails app and I have a _header partial in my layout folder for navbar. I wanna put there a link for Create Profile (user model is created w/ devise, user has_one profile and profile belongs_to user) but only if the user profile doesn't exist yet. 
I would like to create a method for this and put the if statement into the view but I can't figure it out where to create the method and how it would look like.

The basic devise method works fine when it comes to checking if user is signed in. I want a similar method that can check if user profile exists.

layout/_header.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if user.profile(current_user) %>
        <li><%= link_to "Create Profile", new_user_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

So my questions:
Where to put the method (helper/controller/model/appcontroller/etc.)?
How the method would look like?

Comment: You could just do: `unless current_user.try(:profile) link_to "Create profile"...`; or if you're already in a block that has checked for a profile, you can do `if current_user.profile.present? ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in your Helper files (`app/helpers/`). You can use the `application_helper` but for a better consistency we will name this file `users_helper`:

```
# app/helpers/users_helper.rb
module UsersHelper
  def user_has_profile?(user = current_user)
    return false unless user.present?
    Profile.where(user_id: user.try(:id) || user).exists?
  end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
# any view
<% if user_signed_in? && !user_has_profile? %>
```

Comment: MrYoshi, what extra your solution has compared ruby_newbie solution?

Comment: It is almost the same except that you can give a user to the method to check if he has a profile, and it will do a slightly faster SQL request (using `exists` instead of a basic find)

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in the helpers directory(app/helpers/application_helper.rb) as a method called has_profile?

the method would look like

```
def has_profile?
  current_user.profile.present?
end
```

then in your view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && has_profile? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Create Profile", new_user_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I will rather use two if since I have other links to display like Settings that only needs the user_signed_in? method.